# NullPointerException is thrown when tabLayout is created

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Hello I want to create `tabLayout` with the help of `ViewPager` class so that I can swipe among the tabs.

I am creating tabs I setup `fragments`, `viewPagerAdapter` and `viewPager`. Here I initialized `tabLayout` too but I don't understand this error. Please help me to solve.

Here is my main xml which contains tabular layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.davda.musicmain.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="center">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                >
        </include>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code :

```
    tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPagerAdapter.addFrags(new Albums(), "Albums"); // `new Albums()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.addFrags(new Tracks(), "Tracks"); // `new Tracks()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.addFrags(new Artists(), "Artists"); // `new Artists()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Here is stacktrace :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.davda.musicmain, PID: 32662
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.davda.musicmain/com.example.davda.musicmain.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1503)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.davda.musicmain.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6745)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1503) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
Application terminated.
```

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: Okay I am adding Xmls

Comment: post the xml layout and onCreate method

Comment: clean build your apk...

Comment: Not sloved by clean building apk @rafsanahmad007

Answer (score 2):

Just put the `TabLayout` outside the `<include>` tag.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: No @Akash It gives me runtime exception that you must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: @Pedo add your error and mention that in which line you get error.

Comment: Okay I m editing in the question

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this code
1. Check the setContentView() your xml layout is correctly in which xml you have the viewpager,tablayout that must be placed.
2. check the id for tab layout,viewpager.

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_history);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

And

```
  public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
      public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
          super(fragmentManager);
      }
  
      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          if(position == 0) return new CallLogFragment();
          if(position == 1) return new MissedCallFragment();
          if(position == 2) return new ReceivedCallFragment();
          if(position == 3) return new OutgoingCallFragment();

          throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
      }
  
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return 4;
      }
  
      @Override
      public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
          if(position == 0) return "Call Log";
          if(position == 1) return "Missed Call";
          if(position == 2) return "Received Call";
          if(position == 3) return "Outgoing Call";
        
          throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
      }
  }
```

Comment: No this is not a problem these all are correct.

Comment: whats your problem ?